# Can't Access Boot Menu. Wants to Remove Ubuntu and Install Win7

Tags: boot, login

I recently purchased a desktop just for office use. It did not come with an OS. I had someone install Ubuntu to prepare it for ViciDial because I work at home and some clients ask for me to provide for my own dialer. The guy said that I need Ubuntu for the ViciDial to work but he did not finish what he started and I can no longer find him.

I don't know how to use Ubuntu. I searched online on what to do. I followed instructions on what keys to press and my partner and I even went as far as pressing keys from ESC to F12, to Shift (press and hold) and Del but we were still not able to access the boot menu so we can install the Win7 from a CD. Every time we turn the PC on, it just shows a black background with a gray text field in the middle asking for a password. We don't know what the password is.

I'm sorry if I cannot provide other details. I don't have any other information on what he did with the computer. I'm lost and I just want to use my PC again.

In addition, can I still use Win7 if I setup ViciDial?

Answer (score 2):

it's a boot password i think, this article may help:

[How to Secure Your Computer With a BIOS or UEFI Password](http://www.howtogeek.com/186235/how-to-secure-your-computer-with-a-bios-or-uefi-password/)

Comment: Thank you. I went over the article and I did remove the battery before and placed it back but the instruction there about the jumper, that I haven't done yet. I will do this time. Will update.

Comment: I looked for the "jumper" but there's none.. I also removed the battery again just to be sure but it's still the same. When I turned the pc on, it went straight to a black background with a gray text field asking for a password.

Comment: I might not be looking hard enough. I'll scan the board thoroughly this time.

Comment: If you are unable to find the password jumper, consult your motherboard's documentation by looking in the manual or downloading it from the manufacturer's website. 
[see this link:](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000235.htm)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.